# Need some help understanding a weird C behavior

Tags: c

This part of my code works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    //char somestring[3] = "abc";
    int i, j; 
    int count = 5;

    for((i=0) && (j=0); count > 0; i++ && j++){
        printf("i = %d  and j = %d\n", i, j);
        count--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output as expected:

```
i : 0 and j : 0
i : 1 and j : 1
i : 2 and j : 2
i : 3 and j : 3
i : 4 and j : 4
```

Things get weird when I uncomment the char string declaration on the first line of the function body.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char somestring[3] = "abc";
    ...
}
```

The output:

```
i : 0 and j : 4195392
i : 1 and j : 4195393
i : 2 and j : 4195394
i : 3 and j : 4195395
i : 4 and j : 4195396
```

What's the logic behind this? I'm using gcc 4.4.1 on Ubuntu 9.10.

Comment: whats up with i=0 && j=0 ? shouldn't it be i=0, j=0 ? similarly for i++ && j++

Comment: The string `"abc"` takes 4 bytes, not 3. One for the `\0` terminator at the end. Leave the size out of the array and let the compiler fill it in.

Comment: @GMan: Very nice, never saw that one. @Mahesh: As for the weird syntax, I just wanted to play with boolean a little and since I got some false positive from my first example, I didn't pay attention to j not being initialized. Thanks to all.

Comment: Your claimed output doesn't match the `printf()` format string - one has colons and the other equals signs.  The format also has a double space in it that is not shown in the output.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`j` never gets initialised, because of the [short-circuiting behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of `&&`.  Since `(i=0)` evaluates to false, `(j=0)` never gets executed, and hence `j` gets a random value.  In the first example, that just happens to be zero.

You should say `i=0, j=0` to achieve what you want.

The `i++ && j++` has the same problem; it should be `i++, j++`.

Also, this:

```
char somestring[3] = "abc";
```

is reserving one too few bytes, because of the trailing NUL character in the string - you need four bytes.  But if you're not going to modify the string, you don't need to specify the number of bytes - you can simply say this:

```
char *somestring = "abc";
```

instead.

Comment: The last line would be better written as '`char somestring[] = "abc";`' in that it is still an array and modifiable whereas you've transformed `somestring` into a pointer to a non-modifiable area.  It does depend on how the variable is used.  In the initialization phase, you could write '`i = j = 0`'.  Good answer otherwise.

Comment: Your `somestring` is a pointer while the original `somestring` (mike's) was an array. A better solution that wouldn't break existing code was to define `char somestring[] = "abc";`, so that `sizeof` would still return a meaningful value etc..

Comment: @Jonathan, @conio: Good point, but I think it's unlikely that Mike was going to rely on the string being writeable.  I would err on the side of putting strings into write-only memory until I knew I needed to write to them.  Answer amended anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you use &&, only the first argument gets evaluated if it's false. i=0 is false, so j doesn't get set to 0. You should use the komma operator:

```
for((i=0) , (j=0); count > 0; i++, j++){ [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

`for((i=0) && (j=0)...` seems to be incorrect already.
`i=0` has already value of 0, so the evaluation of `j=0` is not needed, so it is skipped.

`(i++) && (j++)` seems to be incorrect for the very first iteration, too, by the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `(i==0) && (j==0)` to initialise both variables in your loop.

However, a property of && is that if the first operand evaluates to FALSE (i.e. 0), the second operand is never executed. So, as i is 0, j is left uninitialised. In your first run, you were simply *lucky* that it happened to contain the value 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables i & j aren't initialized. What do do mean by `(i=0) && (j=0)`?
The compiler will make a shortcut and only assign `i=0` j remains uninitialized with the effect you described.